# Valid palindrome OJ

Tags: c++, string

Given a string, determine if it is a palindrome, considering only alphanumeric characters and ignoring cases. 
For example,
"A man, a plan, a canal: Panama" is a palindrome.
"race a car" is not a palindrome.

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(string s) {
        if (!s.length()) return true;
        int i = 0, j = s.length() - 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < j; ++k)
            s[k] = tolower(s[k]);
        while (i < j) {
            if ((s[i] < 48)||(s[i] > 57 && s[i] < 97)||(s[i] > 122))
                ++i;
            else if ((s[j] < 48)||(s[j] > 57 && s[j] < 97)||(s[j] > 122))
                --j;
            else if (s[i++] != s[j--]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

```
Wrong answer：
Input:  "!bHvX!?!!vHbX" 
Output:   true 
Expected:  false
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: If there were a better time to take up the art of debugging, I'm pressed to think of one.

Comment: What are all those magic numbers?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant asci codes.

Comment: Please don't use magic number instead of the proper character literals. Also, is there a reason you have this function as a (non-static) member function inside a class? The function doesn't depend on anything in the class, so it could just be a normal global function.

Comment: @WhozCraig (FYI, I do realize, but that's not how it ought to be done. Not every system uses ASCII.)

Comment: By the way, you might be interested in e.g. [`std::isalnum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum)

Comment: I hate these _OJ_ questions. They are of no use for anyone seriously researching on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never convert the last character to lower case because the loop condition is k < j and j is the index of the last character. Change the loop to:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= j; ++k)
    s[k] = tolower(s[k]);
```

Also, the code would be a easier to read if you used character constants such as `'a'` instead of ASCII codes.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use "magic numbers". Take into account that apart from ASCII there is EBCDIIC coding scheme.

I would write the function the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

bool IsPalindrome( const std::string &s )
{
    std::string::size_type i = 0, j = s.length();

    do
    {    
            while ( i != j && !std::isalnum( s[i] ) ) ++i;
            while ( j != i && !std::isalnum( s[--j] ) );
    } while ( i != j && std::toupper( s[i] ) == std::toupper( s[j] ) && ++i );


//  Unit test:)
//  std::cout << "i = " << i << ", j = " << j << std::endl;

    return ( i == j );
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama" );

    std::cout << '\"' << s << "\" is palindrome: " 
              << std::boolalpha << IsPalindrome( s ) << std::endl;

    s = "race a car";

    std::cout << '\"' << s << "\" is palindrome: " 
              << std::boolalpha << IsPalindrome( s ) << std::endl;

    s = "!bHvX!?!!vHbX";

    std::cout << '\"' << s << "\" is palindrome: " 
              << std::boolalpha << IsPalindrome( s ) << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
"A man, a plan, a canal: Panama" is palindrome: true
"race a car" is palindrome: false
"!bHvX!?!!vHbX" is palindrome: false
```

You may make the function as the operator function of your class. For example

```
struct Solution
{
   bool operator ()( const std::string & ) const;
};
```

Or

```
struct IsPalindrome
{
   bool operator ()( const std::string & ) const;
};
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct IsPalindrome
{
    bool operator ()( const std::string &s ) const
    {
        std::string::size_type i = 0, j = s.length();

            do
            {    
                while ( i != j && !std::isalnum( s[i] ) ) ++i;
                while ( j != i && !std::isalnum( s[--j] ) );
            } while ( i != j && std::toupper( s[i] ) == std::toupper( s[j] ) && ++i );


//      unit test.:)    
//      std::cout << "i = " << i << ", j = " << j << std::endl;

        return ( i == j );
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v =
    {
        "!bHvX!?!!vHbX",
        "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama",
        "race a car"
    };

    auto it = std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), IsPalindrome() );

    if ( it != v.end() )
    {
        std::cout << '\"' << *it << "\" is palindrome" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
"A man, a plan, a canal: Panama" is palindrome
```

As for your code then even in the first statements of the function there is a bug. You forgot about the last character of the string in the following loop

```
    int i = 0, j = s.length() - 1;
    for (int k = 0; k < j; ++k)
        s[k] = tolower(s[k]);
```

Comment: Not only "there is EBCDIIC coding scheme", but "there are other languages except English", so I'd better rewrite the whole thing with Unicode-aware framework.

Answer (score 0):

You may iterate through the string in both directions until the pointers meet. It will be something like this:

```
bool isPalindrome(std::string const& s) {
    int len = s.length();
    int i = 0;
    int j = len - 1;
    while (true) {
        // Skip garbage characters.
        while (i < len && !isalpha(s[i])) ++i;
        while (j >= 0  && !isalpha(s[j])) --j;

        if (i < j && tolower(s[i]) == tolower(s[j]))
            continue;

        if (i >= j)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Note here `len` is a signed variable, despite `s.length()` is `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript

```
var isPalindrome = function (s) {
    let originalStringWithoutSplChr = s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "").toLowerCase()
    let newString = originalStringWithoutSplChr.split("").reverse().join("")
    if (newString === originalStringWithoutSplChr) {
         return true
    }
    else {
         return false
    }
};
```